# Google Colab: ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to run [some tensorflow projects](https://github.com/rkjones4/GANGogh) on Google Colab, but everytime I get the error below. I have checked that GPU is enabled, and I tried to use instead tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0 with similar results. Any ideas?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-df440c95c76a> in <module>()
      9 
     10 import numpy as np
---> 11 import tensorflow as tf
     12 
     13 import tflib as lib

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Colab is using CUDA 10. You'll need to adjust your code to support CUDA 10 and/or the current version of TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for some hours, here is what works for me.

As `@Bob Smith` mentioned the issue if with the version of CUDA on colab, you can check it using this command :

```sh
cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
```

Then you run the following command line by line to install a lower version of CUDA

```
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64-deb
dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64-deb
apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
apt-get update
apt-get install cuda=9.0.176-1
```

And yupi everything works now, at least at my side :)